# Should I use the <p /> tag in markup?

Tags: html, layout, tags, markup

I have always used either a `<br />` or a `<div/>` tag when something more advanced was necessary.

Is use of the `<p/>` tag still encouraged?

Comment: Could you specify? You question reads that you already use <p></p> (paragraph) tags but when you need something more advanced you use <div> or <br /> (break) tags. What is an instance where you are told to use <p> instead of <div>?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Modern HTML semantics are:

- Use `<p></p>` to contain a paragraph of text in a document.
- Use `<br />` to indicate a line break *inside* a paragraph (i.e. a new line without the paragraph block margins or padding).
- Use `<div></div>` to contain a piece of application UI that happens to have block layout.

Don't use `<div />` or `<p />` on their own. Those tags are meant to contain content. They appear to work as paragraph breaks only because when the browser sees them, and it "helpfully" closes the current block tag before opening the empty one.

Comment: I have a div with both a label and a submit button. I want the submit button on the line after the label. A break seems to work, but you said break should be used inside a paragraph. So what is the right way to put the button on the next line? another div? Adding an arbitrary paragraph to wrap the label and button doesnt seem right.

Comment: Laying out bits of UI is best done with CSS rather than HTML tags. The best solution very much depends on your exact layout requirements. Try googling for things like "css line break" or "css put on new line".

Comment: And there are also [accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p#accessibility_concerns): *"Using empty <p> elements to add space between paragraphs is problematic for people who navigate with screen-reading technology"*

Answer (score 10):

A `<p>` tag wraps around something, unlike an `<input/>` tag, which is a singular item. Therefore, there isn't a reason to use a `<p/>` tag..

---

> I've been told that im using `<br />` when i should use `<p />` instead. – maxp 49 secs ago

If you need to use `<p>` tags, I suggest wrapping the entire paragraph inside a `<p>` tag, which will give you a line break at the end of a paragraph. But I don't suggest just substituting something like `<p/>` for `<br/>`

`<p>` tags are for paragraphs and signifying the end of a paragraph. `<br/>` tags are for line breaks. If you need a new line then use a `<br/>` tag. If you need a new paragraph, then use a `<p>` tag.

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer the question.

Comment: "Is use of the `<p/>` tag encouraged", I'm saying it shouldn't be used, which then should filter down to 'not encouraged'.

Answer (score 10):

### Paragraph is a paragraph, and break is a break.

A `<p>` is like a regular <kbd>Return</kbd> in [Microsoft Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office) [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word). 
A `<br>` is like a soft return, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> in Office Word.

The first one sets all paragraph settings/styles, and the second one barely breaks a line of text.

**Yes, `<p>` elements are encouraged** and won't get deprecated any time soon.

Answer (score 7):

A `<p>` signifies a paragraph. It should be used only to wrap a paragraph of text.

It is more appropriate to use the `<p>` tag for this as opposed to `<div>`, because this is semantically correct and expected for things such as screen readers, etc.

Comment: Can you [include](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1261128/edit) "yes" or "no" in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 6):

Using `<p />` has never been encouraged:

From [XHTML HTML Compatibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/guidelines.html#C_3)

> C.3. Element Minimization and Empty Element Content
>
> Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not
>   EMPTY (for example, an empty title or
>   paragraph) do not use the minimized
>   form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p />`).

Answer (score 4):

From the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> We discourage authors from using empty P elements. User agents should ignore empty P elements.

While they are syntactically correct, empty *[p](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)* elements serve no real purpose and should be avoided.

Comment: What should be used instead? Perhaps include that in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

The HTML [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) does not prohibit you from using an empty `<p>` (a `<p>` element may contain `PCDATA` including the empty string), but it doesn't make much sense to have an empty paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Use it for what? All tags have their own little purpose in life, but no tag should be used for everything. Find out what you are trying to make, and then decide on what tag fits that idea best:

If it is a paragraph of text, or at least a few lines, then wrap it in `<p></p>`

If you need a line break between two lines of text, then use `<br />`

If you need to wrap many other elements in one element, then use the `<div></div>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

The `<p>` tag defines a paragraph. There's no reason for an empty paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

For any practical purpose, you don’t need to add the `</p>` into your markup. But if there is a string XHTML adheration requirement, then you would probably need to close all your markup tags, including `<p>`. Some XHTML analyzer would report this as an error.

Comment: You need to use tick marks to escape HTML tags in posts. I edited them in for you.

Comment: What dictionary has *"adheration"*?