# Anything below the map canvas is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to make a website with a google map embedded. However, anything below the map is not displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 80%; width: 80%; margin: 50px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={my_api_key}&sensor=TRUE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Google map test</div>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
    <div>End of google map test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you look to see in the body section there are three div tags: first line text, second is the map, and third is more text. The first div tag and the map are displaying but the last div tag that says End of google map test is not showing up at all. Do any of you know what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the browser go crazy when I write things like <div/>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218570/why-does-the-browser-go-crazy-when-i-write-things-like-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not close `<div />` like this.

According to the W3C:

```
A div element must have both a start tag and an end tag.
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html

Change This:

```
   <div id="map-canvas"/>
```

To

```
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```