# How can I iterate through tags using Python?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup, loops

I would like to iterate through some html and store data into a dictionary.  Each iteration starts with:

```
<h1 class="docDisplay" id="docTitle">
```

I have the following code:

```
html = '<html><body><h1 class="docDisplay" id="docTitle">Data1</h1><p>other data<\p><h1 class="docDisplay" id="docTitle">Data2</h1><p>other data2<\p></html>'

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
newdoc = soup.find('h1', id="docTitle")
title = newdoc.findNext(text=True)
data = title.findAllNext('p',text=True)
data_dict = {}
data_dict[title] = {'data': data}
print data_dict
```

Right now, the output is

```
{u'Data1': {'data': [u'other data<\\p>', u'Data2', u'other data2<\\p>']}}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{u'Data1': {'data': [u'other data<\\p>']}, u'Data2': {'data': [u'other data2<\\p>']}}
```

I can't figure out how to start again once I reach a new h1 tag.  Any ideas?

Comment: You dont close your </p> correctly. You dont close your body tag either.

Comment: I think that's why he's using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Are you trying to build a dictionary that maps from heading names to the paragraph(s) under each heading?  If that's the case, you have the problem that the all of the `<p>` tags are siblings, so there's no nice way to write something like "find the `<p>` tags in this `<div>` that follows the `<h1>` tag".  You'll probably have to iterate through the `<body>` tag's children, tracking when you encounter headings and paragraphs and making appropriate updates to your dictionary.

Comment: @Josh Rosen:  I see what you're saying.  When I use the findNextAll command, I get all of the p tag contents since they are siblings.  I'm not sure what you mean by "iterate through the <body> tag's children, tracking when you encounter headings and paragraphs and making appropriate updates to your dictionary."  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the text of the paragraphs under each header, I would try something like this (you may have to modify this depending on the exact output format that you want):

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    html = """ 
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1 class="docDisplay" id="docTitle">Data1</h1>
      <p>other data</p>
      <p>Another paragraph under the first heading.</p>
      <h1 class="docDisplay" id="docTitle">Data2</h1>
      <p>other data2</p>
      <div><p>This paragraph is NOT a sibling of the header</p></div>
    </body>
    </html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data_dict = {}
stuff_under_current_heading = []

firstHeader = soup.find('h1', id="docTitle")
for tag in [firstHeader] + firstHeader.findNextSiblings():
    if tag.name == 'h1':
        stuff_under_current_heading = []
        # I chose to strip excess whitespace from the header name:
        data_dict[tag.string.strip()] = {'data': stuff_under_current_heading}
        # Modifying the list modifies the value in the dictionary.
    # Take every <p> tag encountered between here and the next heading
    # and associate it with the most recently-seen <h1> tag.
    elif tag.name == 'p':
        stuff_under_current_heading.append(tag.string)
    # Include <p> tags that are not siblings of the <h1> tag but
    # are still part of the content under the header.
    else:
        stuff_under_current_heading.extend(tag.findAll('p', text=True))

print data_dict
```

This outputs

```
{u'Data1': {'data': [u'other data', u'Another paragraph under the first heading.']},   
 u'Data2': {'data': [u'other data2', u'This paragraph is NOT a sibling of the header']}}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  This is perfect.

Answer (score -1):

@samplebias: @Lynch is right. If the OP doesn't close his/her tags properly, they simply cannot expect for the parser to be able to read their mind.

Try fixing your HTML, it will probably work then. =)

Comment: Actually `<p>` tags don't need to be closed in HTML, and BeautifulSoup knows to close them automatically.

Comment: I know that. I'm saying that if your HTML tags aren't properly structured, you will not get the results you want! A program CANNOT read your mind!

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261104/should-i-use-the-p-tag-in-markup.  Many pages do not properly close their paragraph tags.  The OP probably doesn't have control over the HTML of the page that they're parsing; it's probably from a third party.

Comment: I know that many pages do not close their tags, I realize that I may have been a bit unclear. What I meant to say, is that the OP shouldn't be relying on the program to do the guessing. Not that the program wouldn't guess for him/her. 

Although I do agree that you're right about the not having control part. I didn't consider that. =)