# HTML5 <p> Tags function

Tags: html

Hello Im New in Coding so im just learned about HTML5 and CSS3 and in my Course i found something that makes me confused

So when i see in my course that use HTMl5 you can make Text appearing without using p tag so, whats the different about using p tag and without p tag?

Comment: Search before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261104/should-i-use-the-p-tag-in-markup

Comment: Html does not follow strict mode but Xhtml does. So without p tag also, it will work in html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use the <p /> tag in markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261104/should-i-use-the-p-tag-in-markup)

Answer (score 1):

p tag stands for Paragraph, so if you use p tag, you will let the browser know that is a paragraph, also it's good for Searching engine too
You can use css to style your text

Answer (score 1):

p tags have some properties built in a browser for example:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

They are block elements and have some margin around them. You can display some text without the p tag, but that wouldn't get the styling of a p tag. And you mainly want to style all your p tags with certain properties to make the site design consistent. For example, you want to set the line-height of a p tag and the font-size.

If you just display the text like:

```
<body>
  Hello World!
</body>
```

Hello World would get the styling from the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you need the tags in order to be able to style your text. Besides that, it is a very **bad and uncommon** practice to leave text outside of tags. It just doesn't fit the norms and standards of HTML & CSS. Besides that, tags are important for your SEO (Search Engine Optimization) ranking, which means that e.g. Google needs tags like `<p>` to understand your site and rank it accordingly to the search query.

[Here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51de38728c1ccc246f0058c4) is a link, which may help you understand `<p>` tags better.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use div tag for showing your text

your text

Answer (score 0):

When you work in technologies like **HTML5** and **CSS3** 
you need to know that *all* the text that you write in your .html file is going to show on your page, since it is interpreted as a text string in **HTML5**.

You have lots of tags with which you can show text. When you use 
`<p> some text</ p>`, this indicates that the text within it will contain a **Paragraph**.

If your text is not inside a label, it's a bad practice and you will not have control of it in the future with the help of your **.css** file. (That will be your file to define the styles of your tags used in your **.html** file)

As I mentioned before, there are many labels to contain your texts from titles to buttons (an example of titles we have the tags `<h1>, <h2> ... <h6>` where **h1** will be a title, **h2** a subtitle and so on)

I recommend this website that helps me a lot when it comes to giving my classes since it explains from 0 many of the web technologies and there you can find much more on the subject of tags. regards...
https://www.w3schools.com/