# Python html parsing of div data using bs4

Tags: python, html, pdf, beautifulsoup, apache-tika

Now I want to remove the header and footer of the html page . I have figured out that header and footer appears as last two lines of each div. Can anyone tell me how to extract all the data from a div except the last two lines as below:

```
<div class="page"><p />
<p></p>
<p>First line required
</p>
<p>Second line required
</p>
<p>Third line required
</p>
<p>Line 1 not required
</p>
<p>Line 2 not required
</p>
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="page"><p />
<p>line required 1
</p>
<p></p>
<p>line required 2
</p>
<p>line required 3
</p>
<p></p>
<p>line required 4
</p>
<p>line required 5
</p>
<p>line required 6
</p>
<p>Line 1 not required
</p>
<p>Line 2 not required
<p />
</div>
```

Existing code as below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, 'html.parser')
for num, page in enumerate(soup.select('.page'), 1):
    content = page.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').replace("\n", " ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = """<div class="page"><p />
<p></p>
<p>First line required
</p>
<p>Second line required
</p>
<p>Third line required
</p>
<p>Line 1 not required
</p>
<p>Line 2 not required
</p>
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="page"><p />
<p>line required 1
</p>
<p></p>
<p>line required 2
</p>
<p>line required 3
</p>
<p></p>
<p>line required 4
</p>
<p>line required 5
</p>
<p>line required 6
</p>
<p>Line 1 not required
</p>
<p>Line 2 not required
<p />
</div>"""



#Load the html string into bs4 object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'lxml')

#Strip off empty tags. This also removes empty <p> tags
[x.decompose() for x in soup.findAll(lambda tag: not tag.contents and not tag.name == 'br' )]



#Load all divs with classname = 'page'
items = soup.find_all('',{'class':'page'})

final_html=''
#This for loop removes the last 2 tags from every div (as requested)
for item in items:
    last_item = str(item.find_all('p')[-1])
    second_last_item = str(item.find_all('p')[-2])
    current_item = str(item)
    current_item = current_item.replace(last_item,'')
    current_item = current_item.replace(second_last_item,'')
    final_html = final_html + current_item


final_soup = BeautifulSoup(final_html)
final_str = final_soup.text
print(final_str)
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_str)
--------------------------------
First line required

Second line required

Third line required


line required 1

line required 2

line required 3

line required 4

line required 5

line required 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there can be multiple blank <p> (modified in the html above) in the html which should be ignored. Also the output required is the text without the tags.

Comment: thanks Karthik for your response, This works good with some modifications. Meanwhile I also tried my solution which worked. Attaching below:

Answer (score 2):

```
#import packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, 'html.parser')

for page in soup.find_all("div", class_="page"):
    page.contents[-3].extract()
    page.contents[-1].extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Seems to have the expected effect.

Notes :

- test.html is your html sample
- I had to remove lines -1 and -3, which is probably linked to the strange html you have (`<p>Line 2 not required` never ends, and `<p />` tag does not seems to be a good idea : [Should I use the <p /> tag in markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261104/should-i-use-the-p-tag-in-markup))

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the response. Changed the html. Also there can be multiple blank <p> (modified in the html above) in the html which should be ignored. Also the output required is the text without the tags.